# Android Talkback issues

Tags: android, talkback, accessibilityservice

I'm making my app more "accessible", by checking its behaviour when Talkback is enabled.

Somethings I am struggling with:

- Times are spoken as "seven point one five pm" for 7.15pm
- "pm" is ok but "am" comes out as the word "am" as in "I am"
- dash is spoken as minus when used to separate words

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

An update in case anyone else runs into this.

Their are different accessibility "providers". The built in Google one does not suffer from the issues I have raised.

The Samsung one, however, does so I recommend changing provider to the Google one which is a lot smarter!